# Email-to-activity processing: how to ignore cc

Tags: email, activities

Autofiling inbound emails as activities via EmailProcessor is a really nice feature. However for some CivCRM users it would be nice to have (always and system-wide) only filed activities for the FROM and TO contacts. Is there a way have CC addresses ignored?

Answer (score 1):

You can ALMOST do it with [hook_civicrm_emailProcessorContact](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_emailProcessorContact/), but you don't know at that point which ones are cc's.

But you might be able to do it with [hook_civicrm_emailProcessor](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_emailProcessor/) because there you know which are cc's, except you only have their email not the contact_id. So I admit this is awkward but you could do something like:

1. For each of the cc's, look up the contact id from the email address the same way the email processor does - `CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::matchContactOnEmail($email, 'Individual')->contact_id`
2. The activity_id should be in the $result param in the hook.
3. Delete the corresponding entry in civicrm_activity_contact. (If they were listed both as a To and a Cc you might need to get a little fancier.)